# ASA permit only one host to *.xyz.com

Tags: cisco, nat, cisco-asa, access-control-list

I want to allow a host to download some updates from *.xyz.com (in internet).

How should I permit only this host from my inside network to access *.xyz.com on ASA, access can be via http?

At moment I have no any NAT and I want to implement it via ASDM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that at this moment, all inside hosts have permission to access all external hosts on any port, you need to add two rules:

1. allow access from the inside host to the external host (not a domain) on port 80.
2. deny access from the inside to that external host.

If that assumption is not correct, you need to provide more useful information.

EDIT: I see you added the fact that there is no global NAT pool almost as an afterthought - so does this mean there is currently NO NAT configured from inside to outside, for this inside host ?

If that is the case, you need to configure it; the easiest way is to add a static policy NAT from the internal host to the external host, on port 80; you can use the ASA interface as the translated source address.

This would obviate the need for the access rules above.

Comment: There is no NAT but as you said I need a NAT for inside to outside interfaces.In this case I need a permit ACL for only one Domain Name as destination (the destination can have dynamic or different IPs).